# Spinnaker on Openshift

Tags: openshift, spinnaker

Is it possible for Spinnaker to run and deploy apps on Red Hat's Openshift as a cloud provider? 
If not, what would it take to contibute to make that a reality?

Thanks.

Comment: Since I can't comment on Tomas's answer, here is a link describing how the Kubernetes provider was implemented, linking to key pull requests implementing some of the larger features: https://github.com/spinnaker/spinnaker/wiki/Kubernetes-Implementation

Answer (score 2):

To begin, you would need to create a cloud provider for Openshift and map operations and concepts in Openshift to clouddriver basic operations. To get an idea of the effort, you can look at the Kubernetes commit stream for an idea - https://github.com/spinnaker/clouddriver/pulls?q=is%3Apr+author%3Alwander+is%3Aclosed

Comment: By the way, is there a document describing how to create new cloud providers?

Comment: Openshift does expose the Kubernetes API. So it should be possible to access that from Spinnaker?

Answer (score 1):

<s>We are currently running Spinnaker on OpenShift on Premise.
To make this work we have a bunch of changes in our Spinnaker installation.
We will try to push these upstream. Support is tracked in https://github.com/spinnaker/spinnaker/issues/3760.</s>
We are no longer running Spinnaker on OpenShift.